# Not able to iterate through API response data

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I have a global function named `setAddress`:

```
public setAddress(data) {
    this.address = data['response'];

    console.log(data['response']);
    for (let i of this.address) {
      // console.log('i', i);
      if (i['type'] == 'Primary') {
        this.primaryApplicantAddress.push(i);
      } else if (i['type'] == 'Co-Applicant') {
        this.coApplicantAddress.push(i);
      } else if (i['type'] == 'Guarantor') {
        this.guarantorAddress.push(i);
      } else if (i['type'] == 'Other') {
        this.otherAddress.push(i);
      }
    }
    this.primaryApplicantAddress.splice(0, 1);
    this.coApplicantAddress.splice(0, 1);
    this.guarantorAddress.splice(0, 1);
    console.log('primaryApplicantAddress', this.primaryApplicantAddress);
    console.log('coApplicantAddress', this.coApplicantAddress);
    console.log('guarantorAddress', this.guarantorAddress);
    console.log('address', this.address);
}
```

> console.log(data['response']);

Giving `[object Object]` and console giving error

> this.address is not iterable

I am calling an API and passing response to `setAddress` function.
The response is like:

```
error: false
message_code: ""
response: {Primary: [{name: "Sandeep Kumar Beniwal",…}]}
Primary: [{name: "Sandeep Kumar Beniwal",…}]
0: {name: "Sandeep Kumar Beniwal",…}
Permanent: {mobile: "9001419267", addressLine1: "Chuwas", addressLine2: " ", addressLine3: " Sikar"}
addressLine1: "Chuwas"
addressLine2: " "
addressLine3: " Sikar"
mobile: "9001419267"
name: "Sandeep Kumar Beniwal"
```

In response of api

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through the keys of the JSON Object, here data["response"] is a JSON Object, so you could iterate this item by keys.

For example, having this object

```js
data={};
data["response"]={};
data["response"]["Primary"]={}
data["response"]["Secondary"]={}
data["response"]["Primary"]["name"]=[];
data["response"]["Secondary"]["name"]=[];
data["response"]["Primary"]["name"].push("Name 1");
data["response"]["Primary"]["name"].push("Name 2");
data["response"]["Primary"]["name"].push("Name 3");
data["response"]["Secondary"]["name"].push("SName 1");
data["response"]["Secondary"]["name"].push("SName 2");
data["response"]["Secondary"]["name"].push("SName 3");

this.address = data["response"]
for (var key in this.address) {
   console.log(key, this.address);
   for(let name of this.address[key].name)
        console.log(name);
}
```